# setTimeout/Interval called from within $.each method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little confused, I have read from other places that timeout/interval is the best way to make a function in Javascript run every x seconds. I have to make it so that my function runs every 1 second, as this is a rule for the API I'm using.

My code is as follows:

```
$.each(match_details_json.result.players, function(index, v){
   if (v.account_id == 38440257){ //finds desired playerid
       var match_id_2 = matches[i];
       hero = v.hero_id;
       playerpos = v.player_slot;
       var kills = v.kills;
       var deaths = v.deaths;
       var assists = v.assists;
       var kda = ""+kills+"/"+deaths+"/"+assists+"";
       console.log(match_id_2, hero, playerpos, result, gamemode, kda);
       callback();
       console.log(match_id_2, hero, result, gamemode, kda);
       h=h+1;
       setTimeout(get_match_details(h), 10000);
       i=i+1;
   }
   else{
        console.log('Not desired player, skipping...');   
   }

});
```

Lots of messy code there. But the important part is `setTimeout(get_match_details(h), 10000);`

Whether that is correct or not, that's me trying to say "Run this function again in 10 seconds" and to continue that, until the each method is finished. It doesn't work.

If necessary, here is my `get_match_details` function:

```
function get_match_details(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/ApiMatchPull.php',
            data: {accountid:'38440257', querytype:'GetMatchDetails', querycondition1:'match_id='+matches[h]},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log ('Match Details were was pulled successfully');
                match_details_json = data;
                matchdetailsfill(checkvalidity);
            }
        });
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely what [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) & [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) are for.

So instead of setTimeout, you could use it something like :

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {

       get_match_details(h);

}, 1000);                              // for every second
```

And when you want to stop it, use:

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You execute the function `get_match_details` immedatiately, change your code to

```
setTimeout( function() {
   get_match_details(h)
   }, 10000 );
```

What happens in your code is that you loop through all your players and after 10 seconds as many Ajax calls (`get_match_details`) will be made at the same time.

If you want to have 10 seconds intervals between each ajax call you have to refactor your approach to something like this:

```
  var l = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var c = l.length;
  var ix = -1;
  ajax = function( n ) {
    alert( 'do some ajax with ' + n )
  }
  call = function() {
    if( c > ++ix ) {
        ajax( l[ ix ] );
        setTimeout( function() { call(); }, 1000 );

    }
  }
  call();
```